# How to continuously watch and read file asynchronously in Rust using tokio

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I would like to extract data continuously from some `systemd` log files. I have a regular expression which extracts what I'm interested in. What I'm not sure about is how to continously digest that file. I'm using `tokio` to keep things asynchronous.

I'm wondering if I should regularly (e.g. once per second) open that file, read into a buffer until the previously last line is matched, if I can keep that file open (I don't think this is a good idea from my `Python` experience, but I'm not sure if that would be ok in `rust`) or if there is another more elegant way to achieve that.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You could look at [notify](https://docs.rs/notify), but it doesn't appear to support async and the API looks tightly coupled with std::mpsc so might be hard to make it work nicely with tokio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read into a buffer until the previously last line is matched. Instead, keep track of your position in the file then [`seek`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncSeek.html#tymethod.start_seek) to that position. You can make sure the seeked text matches (and that the seek succeeds) to be sure the file hasn't been rotated or truncated.

As for when to read, you can poll or you can use an API that notifies you of changes. I haven't used it, but I found the [notify](https://docs.rs/notify/latest/notify/) crate with a quick search. In addition to the crate documentation, the page [here](https://github.com/notify-rs/notify/wiki/The-Event-Guide) looks useful.

Comment: Thanks that worked! For the sake of completeness I'll post my solution based on your input. I'm happy to take any feedback :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comment from piojo I found this a viable solution for me:

```
    let mut file = File::open(path).await.unwrap();
    let mut interval = time::interval(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    let mut contents = vec![];
    let mut position = 0;
    
    loop {
        contents.truncate(0);
        file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(position as u64)).await;
        position += file.read_to_end(&mut contents).await.unwrap();
        
        /// do_process(contents)
        
        interval.tick().await;
    }
```

Comment: It's nice that you're posting your solution. BTW, instead of allocating a new vec in each loop iteration, you can call `contents.truncate(0)`. And you should be able to set `last_position += read_to_end()` and not need an extra call.

Comment: And lastly, a common pattern is to make most or all of your functions return `Result<_>`, and within them, call `foo?` instead of `foo.unwrap()`. That will cascade any errors upwards, but if you decide you want to handle them, you can. (But the functions may return different error types, so people use a helper library for error handling. I use `anyhow` and return `anyhow::Result<_>`. But your code is fine! These are just tips.

Comment: Last comment (I promise): you should check your CPU usage. It's likely that if you don't use `notify` (or just let the thread sleep), the loop will peg one core at 100%.

Comment: It appears that `file.read_to_end()` returns that last position as `usize`. Therefore, I need to create another `SeekFrom::Start` enum, right? However, the code is already much nicer that way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding the loop it looks actually fine with the `interval.tick` running this asynchronously. It's less elegant than `notify`, though.

Comment: What a about this for eliminating the need for two variables? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f5c313c2a4edaf6147db009f4e99b62